# PHP help with image source changing depending on date?

Tags: php, variables, date

What I want to do is show three images. The images that show up depend on the month.
There should be an image for the previous month, the current month, and the next month.

This is what I have..

```
  //Dates
  $prevDate = date("M Y", strtotime("-1 months"));
  $currDate = date("M Y");
  $nextDate = date("M Y", strtotime("+1 months"));

  $prevMonth = $prevDate.date("M");
$currMonth = $currDate.date("M");
$nextMonth = $nectDate.date("M");

//Years
$prevYear = $prevDate.date("Y");
$currYear = $currDate.date("Y");
$nextYear = $nextDate.date("Y");


  echo '<img src="./images/' + $prevMonth + '_' + $prevYear + '.jpg"/>';
```

What I end up getting is "0" on the page. 
I havent worked with php for about 2 years so I am really rusty! any help?

What I would want it to do is have it connect to images named "december_2011.jpg"

Comment: Not that this is going to fix things, but you have a typo - $nextMonth = $nectDate, instead of $nextDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code :

```
//Months
  $prevMonth = date("M");
  $currMonth = date("M");
  $nextMonth = date("M");
```

will give the same value for the 3 variables : the current month : "Dec"

This mean :

```
//Years
  $prevYear = $prevMonth.date("Y");
  $currYear = $currMonth.date("Y");
  $nextYear = $nextMonth.date("Y");
```

will give you the same things too : "Dec2010" (`.` is for concatenation in PHP)

Finally :

```
echo '<img src="./images/' + $prevMonth + '_' + $prevYear + '.jpg"/>';
```

should be

```
echo '<img src="./images/'.$prevMonth.'_'.$prevYear.'.jpg"/>';
```

**"." for concatenation and not "+" like in javascript**

You could resolve this this way :

```
//Dates
$prevDate = date("M_Y", strtotime("-1 months"));
$currDate = date("M_Y");
$nextDate = date("M_Y", strtotime("+1 months"));

echo '<img src="./images/'.$currDate.'.jpg"/>';
echo '<img src="./images/'.$prevDate.'.jpg"/>';
echo '<img src="./images/'.$nextDate.'.jpg"/>';
```

To help you what it renders, [here is the codepad example](http://codepad.org/p9vnHAEw).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike many other languages `.` is the concatenation operator, not the syntax for 'member-of' (that would be `->`). Besides, the interface for `date` is procedural (no objects) anyway.

Consider this:

```
function filename_of_time($time) { 
  return '<img src="./images/'.date('M_Y',$time).'.jpg"/>');
}

echo filename_of_time(strtotime("-1 month"));
echo filename_of_time(time());
echo filename_of_time(strtotime("+1 month"));
```